# Running time:schedule-event does not work

Tags: netlogo

I'm rather new to NetLogo but I want to simulate the collective charging behaviour of drivers. For now, I want to implement a schedule (e.g. that the drivers are on the road between 8am and 5pm and therefore are eligible to charge before and after these hours). In order to do so, I anchored the time to the ticks. But now the implementation of the "to setup-schedule" does not work. I already looked at the collinsheppard/time example: "Discrete Event Scheduling" but that does not run either on my computer (an internal error is announced). I would appreciate your help a lot!

```
extensions time]

globals [
  cars-charging      ;; number of cars charging
  blackout-patch     ;; patch showing the blackout label
  home-patches       ;; agentset of green patches representing BEVs being at home
  charge-patches     ;; agentset of blue patches representing the charging stations
  work-patches       ;; agentset of grey patches representing BEVs not being at home
  energy-demanded    ;; kW requested by BEVs in charging events
  q                  ;; probability of driving somewhere (i.e. work)
  tick-datetime      ;; time in the model
  ; blackout-threshold
]

turtles-own [
  battery-level
  battery-level-minimum
  charge?
]


to setup
  __clear-all-and-reset-ticks

  ;; set the start date to January 1, 2020 and link the ticks to one hour
  time:anchor-schedule time:create "2020-01-01 00:00" 1 "hour"
  set tick-datetime time:anchor-to-ticks (time:create "2020-01-01 00:00") 1 "hour"

  setup-world

  setup-turtles

  setup-schedule

end

to setup-world
    ;; Creation of Work
  set work-patches patches with [pxcor > 1 and pycor < 1]
  ask work-patches [set pcolor 37
  ]

  ;; Creation of Home
  set home-patches patches with [pxcor < 1]
  ask home-patches [set pcolor 57 ]

  ;; Creation of Charging Stations
  set charge-patches patches with [pxcor > 1 and pycor > 1]
  ask charge-patches [ set pcolor 98 ]


  ;; use one of the patch labels to visually indicate whether or not the electricity grid is overloaded
  ask patch (1 * max-pxcor) (0.33 * max-pycor) [
    set blackout-patch self
    set plabel-color red
  ]
end

to setup-turtles

  crt 10

  ask turtles [
    set size 1
    set shape "car"
    set color 105
    move-to-empty-one-of home-patches    ;; start at without charging and at home
   ]
end

to setup-schedule
  ;; schedule all of the turtles to perform the "move-to-empty-one-of" work-patches procedure at 12am
  time:schedule-event turtles [ [] -> move-to-empty-one-of work-patches ] time:create "2020-01-01 12:00"

  ;; See what's on the schedule
  ;print time:show-schedule
end

to go
  ;; stop when there is a blackout
  if energy-demanded > blackout-threshold [stop]

  ;; update the global variables
  ask blackout-patch [ set plabel "" ]

  ;; advance the clock
  tick
end


to move-to-empty-one-of [locations]  ;; turtle procedure of not using the same patch = same charging station
  move-to one-of locations
  while [any? other turtles-here]
  [move-to one-of locations]
end
```

Comment: Telling us that it doesn't work does not provide enough information. Does it produce an error and, if so, what does the error message say? Does the model behaviour look wrong? If so, what should have happened and what did happen instead?

Comment: No error is produced. The model just does not react to that order at all. Is there another option, apart from the discrete event scheduling, to make agents perform an action at a certain number of ticks? Unfortunately, I only found the time extension which, according to Mr. Railsback does not work properly at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a tick representing one hour and you want all your turtles to go to do something at a particular time each day, then just use the `mod` function. Something like:

```
if ticks mod 24 = 9 [ask turtles [go-to-work] ]
```

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid that the discrete event scheduling part of the time extension is not working with the current version of NetLogo. (The rest of the extension still does, even though you may get a warning when starting a model with NetLogo 6.1.)

The NetLogo development team started to fix the time extension for packaging with NetLogo but the work seems to have slowed down. (The original programmer of the extension is no longer available to support it.) I will ask them to give it more priority but anyone else wanting to do discrete event simulation (in addition to the extension's other features, such as linking ticks to specific amounts of time) might also want to let the developers know.